# Projecting a given point onto a random $2$-dimensional plane in more than $3$ dimensions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-probability

We are given $\mathbf{p}\in\mathbb{R}^d$, where $d\gg 1$. Let $\mathbf{v}$ be a point selected *uniformly at random* from the unit $(d-1)$-sphere $\mathcal{S}^{d-1}$ centered at the origin $\mathbf{0}\in\mathbb{R}^d$, and $H:=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^d : \langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v}\rangle=0\}$ be the *random* hyperplane orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}$ and passing through the origin.

A commonly used method to project $\mathbf{p}$ onto $H$ consists in generating $d$ Gaussian random variables $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_d$, defining $\mathbf{v}=\frac{\mathbf{z}}{\|\mathbf{z}\|_2}$, and then finding the projection $\mathbf{p}'$ of $\mathbf{p}$ onto $H$ by calculating $\mathbf{p}'=\mathbf{p}-\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{p}\rangle\,\mathbf{v}$.

---

**Question:** What is a natural way to extend the above technique to project $\mathbf{p}$ onto a random $2$-dimensional plane $P$ passing through the origin - thereby defining $P$ by extending the definition of $H$ from $d$ to $2$ dimensions still in $\mathbb{R}^d$, viz., in such a way that selecting a point uniformly at random from the intersection $\mathcal{S}^{d-1} \cap P$ is equivalent to selecting a point uniformly at random from $\mathcal{S}^{d-1}$?

---

---

***Proposed solution:*** *We can select uniformly at random two points $\mathbf{v}'$ and $\mathbf{v}''$ from the unit $(d-1)$-sphere $\mathcal{S}^{d-1}$ centered at the origin. We can then find the (unique) plane $P$ containing $\mathbf{v}'$, $\mathbf{v}''$ and the origin. To project $\mathbf{p}$ onto $P$ defined this way, we could finally represent  any point $\mathbf{x}$ of $P$ as $\mathbf{x}:=a\,\mathbf{v}'+b\,\mathbf{v}''$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, and find the (unique) value of $a$ and the (unique) value of $b$ minimizing the distance $\|\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{x}\|_2$.*
***Questions:*** *How can we prove that this solution is correct? Is there a simpler and faster solution?*

Comment: You could project onto a random $d-1$-plane, then a random $d-2$-plane inside it, and so on until you wound up projecting onto a random 2-plane. I don't know how it compares to your algorithm.

Comment: Yes, @HughThomas , I did not think about it. Interesting, it is conceptually more straightforward (indeed, you explained it in two lines). However, the number of operations seems to me significantly larger, say $d$-many times larger up to a constant factor if I am not wrong.

Comment: What you describe sounds simple enough: note that you can get $\mathbf{x}$ from applying Gram-Schmidt to the vectors $\mathbf{v}',\mathbf{v}'',\mathbf{p}$. You may want to clarify what you mean by "then all angles between $\mathbf{u}$ and a positive coordinate axes of $\mathbb{R}^d$ are selected independently uniformly at random from $[0,2\pi)$".

Comment: Thank you @TimothyBudd . I rephrased the sentence by writing "all angles between $\mathbf{u}$ and the positive coordinate axes of $\mathbb{R}^d$ follow a uniform distribution over the interval $[0,2\pi)$", which is a condition to define the random choice of $P$ (by extending in a "natural" way the random choice of $H$).

Comment: As a small remark, there is a formula extending the formula you are using for projecting onto a random hyperplane. If you have 2 hyperplanes, described as the orthogonal complements of $v_1$ and $v_2$ respectively, then the extended formula would involve the inverse of the Gram matrix of $v_1$ and $v_2$. If you want, I can figure it out and write it down.

Comment: Yes, thank you @Malkoun !

Comment: Characterizing uniform distribution by the angles with coordinate axes doesn't seem to work. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, if a plane $P$ makes an angle $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ with an axis $D$, then the angle between $D$ and any unit vector in $P$ will be in $[\theta,\pi/2]$, hence not uniformly distributed.

Comment: Sorry @LaurentMoret-Bailly . Perhaps I am missing your point. What you wrote is correct, but in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the conditions on the distributions of the angles are indeed implied by randomly choosing $P$ as we randomly choose $H$ (described above). Furthermore, the implication goes in the opposite direction too, thereby showing that the condition of the distribution angles is equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to choosing  $P$ as we choose $H$. This fact does not contradict what you wrote in your comment, which is in fact about a *conditional* probability, right?

Comment: What I wrote about the distribution of the angles is basically equivalent to write that $\mathbf{u}$ is indeed a point selected uniformly at random from $\mathcal{S}^{d-1}$, i.e., in $\mathbb{R}^3$ it is selected uniformly at random from the unit sphere centered at the origin $\mathbf{0}\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: OK, but your phrasing (starting with "if u is a vector selected...") suggests taht the uniform distribution holds for any given $P$. I guess it is too late for me to get used to probabilistic parlance. From my naive stand, there is no such thing as a "random plane"!

Comment: Thank you for your comment @LaurentMoret-Bailly .  I rephrased the second part of the question. I hope is more formal and clearer. By the way, I guess it is correct to say that if we have a set $S$ of geometrical objects (e.g., a set of planes in the Euclidean space), then we can define a probability distribution over $S$ to sample one of this object from $S$, thereby selecting a *random* object (e.g., a random plane).

Comment: This is what I hear all the time. But again: no object can be called "random". I seriously suggest you think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ linearly independent, their Gram matrix $G$ is defined to be
$$ G = V^T V, $$
where $V = (v_1 v_2)$ is the $d \times 2$ matrix having $v_1$ as first column and $v_2$ as second column. More explicitly, we have
$$ G = \begin{pmatrix} (v_1, v_1) & (v_1, v_2) \\ (v_2, v_1) & (v_2, v_2) \end{pmatrix}, $$
where $(-,-)$ denotes the Euclidean inner product in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

To project a vector $p \in \mathbb{R}^d$ onto the linear span of $v_1$ and $v_2$ amounts to solving
$$ V x = p $$
in the least-square sense, i.e. finding $x = (x_1, x_2)^T$ such that the $\lVert Vx - p \rVert^2$ is minimized.

Hence you want $Vx - p$ to be orthogonal to $v_1$ and $v_2$ (for details, read about the least-square method). Hence you want
$$ (Vx - p, Vy) = 0, $$
for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$. This implies that
$$ (V^T(Vx - p), y) = 0 $$
for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Hence
$$ V^TV x = V^T p $$
or
$$ G x = V^T p, $$
so that
$$ x = G^{-1} V^T p. $$

More explicitly, if
$$ G^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}, $$
then
$$ \begin{align} x_1 &= a (p, v_1) + b (p, v_2) \\
x_2 &= c (p, v_1) + d (p, v_2), \end{align} $$
and $x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2$ is the desired orthogonal projection of $p$ onto the linear span of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

I did not answer your questions about uniform distribution etc., but this was too long as a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much @Malkoun, I did not know this method.